# Get number of lines in buffer client-server java

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I have a client-server java program that uses sockets. The client uses a bufferedreader to read from the socket using a simple `while ((input = buffer.readLine()) != null)` loop. I want to make the client skip lines in the buffer if too many lines accumulate, i.e: the client can't keep up with the server.
So in essence what I need is a simple way to see how many lines are left in the buffer, while still allowing those lines to be read later.

Comment: Once you read them from the `buffer` they are gone from the `buffer`. You can't allow it to read them later while skipping over them. You can just store them though somewhere... (the ones you want to skip that is)